# Virtual function or virtual method, which one is appropriate?

Tags: virtual

I have been to many interviews, where always a question interviewers used to ask "Do you know virtual function?"
I always wonder why experienced programmer/developer use function with virtual. As much I know.. not all functions can be virtual, only those functions which are part of any class/struct can be virtual.

So I think "Function is superset and method is subset. Not all functions can be methods but, all methods are functions. Therefore it would be appropriate to use "virtual method" not "virtual function".

Can somebody explain, why most of the experienced programmer and even technical books write use "virtual function" not "virtual method"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically methods are those that belong to classes and functions are the ones that don't, but like with other things that are so general and common, people end up mixing up the terminology and in the end "function" and "method" can both refer to one thing or the other. That's pretty much the answer to your question... In the end, terminology is defined by how people use it, not by the original intended meanings.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this link can help you :-

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/oops/4a0J170612-Difference-between-function-and-method.html

Yes, linguistically or logically the functions are **not** the part of the class, but methods are the **members** of the class.

Or, in more simple words, methods don't have their own existence, they belong to class. But the functions have their own existence.

I hope this might also have clarified your doubts.